# Passing itself value into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following and you can see I am trying to pass `this` through on the function is this possible in JavaScript\jQuery if so how? Can't seem to find anything I think I have the terminology wrong.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        jQuery(".ShowPleaseWait").click(function () {
            processingReplacer("Please Wait...", this);
        });
        jQuery(".ShowProcessing").click(function () {
            processingReplacer("Processing...", this);
        });
    }
}

function processingReplacer(message, this) { 
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
            jQuery(this).after("<img id='" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + "' class='" + jQuery(this).attr('class') + "' src='/content/images/processing.gif' /> " + message);
            alert("woohoo"); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
processingReplacer.call(this, "Please Wait...");
```

...

```
function processingReplacer(message) { 
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
            jQuery(this).after("<img id='" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + "' class='" + jQuery(this).attr('class') + "' src='/content/images/processing.gif' /> " + message);
            alert("woohoo"); 
        }
}
```

using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) you are able to set the context of `this`. However Jon's answer is probably more readable.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `this` as the name of a function parameter. Change it to something else:

```
function processingReplacer(message, target) { 
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        jQuery(target).hide();
        jQuery(target).after("<img id='" + jQuery(target).attr('id') + "' class='" +
           jQuery(target).attr('class') + "' src='/content/images/processing.gif' /> " +
           message);
        alert("woohoo"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon its more readable but my requirements require me to use this.